# error on sending parameter values on event call

Tags: chatbot, dialogflow-es

I have an intent which I am trying to invoke using event name, and trying to send parameters with it.

```
query_input = {
    'event': {
      "name": "greet",
      "parameters": {
        "mobile": "9876543210",
        "plan": "pizza plan",
      },
      "language_code": "en"
    }
}
response = session_client.detect_intent(session, query_input)
```

But I am getting error

> ValueError: Protocol message Struct has no "mobile" field.

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now, I am sending parameters as below, its working fine:

```
from google.protobuf import struct_pb2
parameters = struct_pb2.Struct()
parameters["mobile"] = "9876543210"
parameters["plan"] = "pizza plan"
query_input = {
    'event': {
        "name": "greet",
        "parameters": parameters,
        "language_code": "en"
    }
}
response = session_client.detect_intent(session, query_input)
```